# How to move from both rvalue and lvalue arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, move, lvalue, rvalue

Having a class `Widget` with default and move constructors, I'd like to write a function that:

1. accepts **both** lvalues and rvalues of type `Widget` as an argument,
2. internally 'moves' from this argument, e.g., to some other `Widget` instance.

For example:

```
Widget w;
auto p1 = pointer_from_lrvalue(Widget()); // rvalue argument
auto p2 = pointer_from_lrvalue(w); // lvalue argument
// w is guaranteed to be no longer used from now on
```

where `pointer_from_lrvalue()` might look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> pointer_from_lrvalue(Widget w) {
   return std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new Widget(std::move(w)));
}
```

Such a *passing-by-value approach* shows Andrei Alexandrescu in his `scopeGuard()` function [[ErrorHandling-slides](http://sdrv.ms/RXjNPR), page 48]. However, the drawback of this approach is that it **requires a copy constructor** of `Widget` in case of passing an lvalue argument `w` (at least with g++ 4.9.2).

I was able to find the following solutions to prevent calling/requiring a copy constructor. The first one uses lvalue and rvalue references:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> pointer_from_lrvalue(Widget& w) {
   return std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new Widget(std::move(w)));
}    
std::unique_ptr<Widget> pointer_from_lrvalue(Widget&& w) {
   return std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new Widget(std::move(w)));
}
```

The second one uses a universal reference:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<T>> pointer_from_lrvalue(T&& t) {
   return std::unique_ptr<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
       (new std::remove_reference_t<T>(std::move(t)));
}
```

I wonder:

1. Whether these solutions are correct and are guaranteed not to call the `Widget` copy constructor?
2. Which of these two solutions should I prefer?
3. Is there another, possibly better, solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, they're both correct and guaranteed to only invoke moves.
2. This is rather subjective. I would personally prefer the forwarding reference, because I hate code duplication. However, it does require putting the code in a header.
3. If you want to go fancy, you can create your own non-template "movable `Widget` reference:"

   ```
   class WidgetMover
   {
     Widget& widget;

   public:
     Widget&& moveWidget() { return std::move(widget); }

     WidgetMover(Widget &w) : widget(w) {}
     WidgetMover(Widget &&w) : widget(w) {}
   };

   std::unique_ptr<Widget> pointer_from_lrvalue(WidgetMover w) {
      return std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new Widget(w.moveWidget()));
   }
   ```

   Care must be taken to ensure that no `WidgetMover` lives beyond the lifetime of an rvalue it might have been initialised with.